# Codeigniter: Pagination Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

In pagination I am getting error when try to go to any pages than first page (offset=0) here is my code

**URI:** `http://localhost/the-site/admin/hr/career_new/`

**URI with offset:** `http://localhost/the-site/admin/hr/career_new/employee_id/desc/3`

**Error1**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: .../career_model.php
Line Number: 127
```

**Error2**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: .../career_model.php
Line Number: 127
```

***The error line I have commented `This is the error line #127` in below model code. It is right before `return $ret`***

**Model**

```
public function sort($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order)
{

    $type          = $this->input->post('type');
    $emp_id        = $this->input->post('employee_id');
    $old_operation = $this->input->post('old_operation');
    $old_position  = $this->input->post('old_position');
    $new_operation = $this->input->post('new_operation');
    $new_position  = $this->input->post('new_position');
    $created       = $this->input->post('record_date');
    $effect        = $this->input->post('effective_date');

    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    $sort_columns = array(
        'type',
        'employee_id',
        'old_operation',
        'old_position',
        'new_operation',
        'new_position',
        'record_date',
        'effective_date',
        'reason',
    );

    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'id';

    // results query
    $q = $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('career_path')
            ->like('type', $type)
            ->like('employee_id', $emp_id)
            ->like('old_operation', $old_operation)
            ->like('old_position', $old_position)
            ->like('new_operation', $new_operation)
            ->like('new_position', $new_position)
            ->like('record_date', $created)
            ->like('effective_date', $effect)
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();

    // count query
    $q = $this->db
            ->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
            ->from('career_path')
            ->like('type', $type)
            ->like('employee_id', $emp_id)
            ->like('old_operation', $old_operation)
            ->like('old_position', $old_position)
            ->like('new_operation', $new_operation)
            ->like('new_position', $new_position)
            ->like('record_date', $created)
            ->like('effective_date', $effect)
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $temp = $q->get()->result();
    $ret['num_rows'] = $temp[0]->count; // This is the error line #127

    return $ret;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function career_new($sort_by = 'employee_id', $sort_order = 'desc', $offset = 0)
{
    $this->data['title'] = '<i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> ' . lang('crr_add');

    /*         * ***********************************************************
     * load loop with pagination
     * ****************************************************************** */

    $limit = get_option('per_page');

    // fields
    $this->data['columns'] = array(
        'id'             => 'ID',
        'type'           => 'Type',
        'employee_id'    => 'Employee ID',
        'old_operation'  => 'Old Operation',
        'old_position'   => 'Old Position',
        'new_operation'  => 'New Operation',
        'new_position'   => 'New Position',
        'record_date'    => 'Created',
        'effective_date' => 'Effected',
    );

    $results                   = $this->career_model->sort($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);
    $this->data['careers']     = $results['rows'];
    $this->data['num_results'] = $results['num_rows'];

    $base_url   = base_url() . 'admin/hr/career_new/' . $sort_by . '/' . $sort_order;
    //$numbs      = $this->employees_model->filter_count();
    $total_rows = $this->data['num_results'];

    get_pagination($base_url, $total_rows, $limit, 6, 2, TRUE);

    //$this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->data['sort_by']    = $sort_by;
    $this->data['sort_order'] = $sort_order;

    /*         * ***********************************************************
     *  End: load loop with pagination
     * ****************************************************************** */

    $this->data['career'] = $this->career_model->get_new();

    $rules = $this->career_model->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        //db fields/columns to insert value
        $crr_fields = array(
            'type',
            'employee_id',
            'old_operation',
            'old_position',
            'new_operation',
            'new_position',
            'record_date',
            'effective_date',
            'reason',
        );

        $data = $this->career_model->array_from_post($crr_fields);

        if (empty($data['reason'])) {
            $data['reason'] = NULL;
        }

        $this->career_model->save($data);

        $data['old_position']  = get_employee_id_field($data['employee_id'], 'position');
        $data['old_operation'] = get_employee_id_field($data['employee_id'], 'operation');

        /* ----------------------------------------------------------------
         * Sending email once form validation runs true
          --------------------------------------------------------------- */
        $email_hr       = $this->config->item('hr_email_templates');
        $email_template = $this->config->item('crr_new_email');
        $message = $this->load->view($email_hr . $email_template, $data, true);

        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->from('atlassystem@apolloblake.com', get_config_option('site_name'));
        $this->email->to(get_user_data('email', 1));
        $this->email->subject(get_config_option('site_name') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('crr_new_subject'));
        $this->email->message($message);

        if ($this->email->send()) {
            // set session notification message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', sprintf(lang('crr_record_added'), '#' . $data['employee_id']));
            $this->data['message']      = $this->session->flashdata('message');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message_type', 'success');
            $this->data['message_type'] = $this->session->flashdata('message_type');

            redirect(current_url(), 'refresh');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('hr/career/form', $this->data);
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('hr/career/form', $this->data);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="panel-body"> 

    <?php
    if (validation_errors()):
        echo show_alert(validation_errors(), TRUE, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign');
    endif;
    ?>

    <div class="table-responsive">                    
        <table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0" border = "0" class = "table table-hover table-bordered datatables center" id = "">
            <thead>
                <tr class = "active center">

                    <?php foreach ($columns as $field_name => $field_display): ?>

                        <th <?= ($sort_by == $field_name ) ? "class=\"sort_$sort_order\"" : NULL ?>>
                            <?= anchor("admin/hr/career_new/$field_name/" . (($sort_order == 'asc' && $sort_by == $field_name) ? 'desc' : 'asc'), $field_display); ?>
                            <?= (($sort_order == 'asc' && $sort_by == $field_name) ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>'); ?>
                        </th>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($careers as $crr):
                    echo '<tr>';
                    foreach ($columns as $field_name => $field_display):
                        echo '<td>', $crr->$field_name, '</td>';
                    endforeach;
                    echo '</tr>';
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table><!--end table-->
    </div> 
    <?php if (strlen($pagination)): ?>
        <div>
            <?= $pagination; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

**var_dump output**

using `var_dump($temp);` in model I am getting below on `$offset=0` means first page

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'count' => string '7' (length=1)
```

and `var_dump($ret['num_rows']);`

```
tring '7' (length=1)
```

On second page with `offset=3` getting error with below `var_dump` output

```
var_dump($temp);

array (size=0)
  empty
```

and

```
var_dump($ret['num_rows']);

null
```

Comment: What if you change "$temp = $q->get()->result();" to "$temp = $q->get()->result_array();"

Comment: @Craig hmm.. let me try..

Comment: Oops.. It's messed up everything since it's now resulting array. So my view also got affected. So I thing there should be some other solution to it

Comment: I am updating question with `var_dump()`

Comment: @karanthakkar there is a still error. Just a difference is instead of two error I am getting only one (I mean same error message)

Comment: Error is the same just display two times

Comment: on same line ?? @CodeLover

Comment: Nope I am sorry there are two different error for the same line. I have updated in question please have look that one

Comment: you havent tried solution yet.
replace those 2 lines with
 `$temp = $q->get()->row();
$ret['num_rows'] = $temp->count;`

Comment: @karanthakkar I have tried that one and I gave my response on that too. After your code it is giving one error instead of tow. `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: .../career_model.php
Line Number: 126`

Comment: $ret['num_rows'] = $q->num_rows();

Comment: @Craig something wrong with the code giving error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows()`

Comment: $temp = $this->db->get();
$ret['num_rows'] = $temp->num_rows();

Comment: With latest fix, no pagination shown up.. but when I tried to entered URL manually than it works without error...but again now pagination shown up..

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have fixed the issue. It was a small and simple yet took my 4-5 hours to find and fix it.

I just did copy and paste for result and count query in model and there I made a mistake. I just overlooked the last two `->limit()`, and `->order_by()` function which was not required for count total rows. This was creating issue. When use pagination it was counting limit and offset. So final fixed code is as below

**Model**

```
public function sort($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order)
{

    $type          = $this->input->post('type');
    $emp_id        = $this->input->post('employee_id');
    $old_operation = $this->input->post('old_operation');
    $old_position  = $this->input->post('old_position');
    $new_operation = $this->input->post('new_operation');
    $new_position  = $this->input->post('new_position');
    $created       = $this->input->post('record_date');
    $effect        = $this->input->post('effective_date');

    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    $sort_columns = array(
        'type',
        'employee_id',
        'old_operation',
        'old_position',
        'new_operation',
        'new_position',
        'record_date',
        'effective_date',
        'reason',
    );

    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'id';

    // results query
    $q = $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('career_path')
            ->like('type', $type)
            ->like('employee_id', $emp_id)
            ->like('old_operation', $old_operation)
            ->like('old_position', $old_position)
            ->like('new_operation', $new_operation)
            ->like('new_position', $new_position)
            ->like('record_date', $created)
            ->like('effective_date', $effect)
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();

    // count query
    $q = $this->db
            ->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
            ->from('career_path')
            ->like('type', $type)
            ->like('employee_id', $emp_id)
            ->like('old_operation', $old_operation)
            ->like('old_position', $old_position)
            ->like('new_operation', $new_operation)
            ->like('new_position', $new_position)
            ->like('record_date', $created)
            ->like('effective_date', $effect); // removed limit and order_by

    $temp = $q->get()->result();
    $ret['num_rows'] = $temp[0]->count; // This is the error line #127

    return $ret;
}
```